# Save view to Image crashes

Tags: swiftui, printing

I've been adding a Print to PDF feature to my app utilizing the tutorial from the video https://youtu.be/rDQ5ENvJxyc?feature=shared ...

I am having a weird hang that I can't debug.  Whenever I have more subviews than fit on the screen (usually when I have more than four Cards showing in my App), selecting the export PDF option freezes the App.

I've run it in the debugger, but can't figure out how to capture the hang.
I tried putting a break point in the exportPDF code at the do {}catch {}  I can see a valid pdfView

```
(lldb) po pdfView
<UIScrollView: 0x105823600; frame = (0 59; 430 942); clipsToBounds = YES; tag = 1009; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x2819abea0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x281700200>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {430, 942}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}>
```

But it will hang as soon as I leave the closure.. never getting to the break point I set on getRootController().view.subviews.forEach

I'm attaching my View controller that calls the code as found in the attached Video for any suggestions on how to debug this.  I have simplified it to remove the CoreData Query and property definitions

I have not included the code from the above video, which I have confirmed is verbatim in my code. (I can attach if needed).

```
struct ViewEventsView: View {
    // MARK: PDF Properties
    @State var PDFUrl: URL?
    @State var showShareSheet: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                        AddressView(recipient: recipient)
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 250, height: 150)
                    }  
                }
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVGrid(columns: gridLayout, alignment: .center, spacing: 5) {
                        ForEach(events, id: \.self) { event in
                            HStack {
                                VStack {
                                    Image(uiImage: (event.cardFrontImage ?? blankCardFront)!)
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .scaledToFit()
                                        .frame(width: iPhone ? 120 : 200, height: iPhone ? 120 : 200)
                                        .padding(.top, iPhone ? 2: 5)
                                    HStack {
                                        VStack {
                                            Text("\(event.event ?? "")")
                                                .foregroundColor(.green)
                                            Spacer()
                                            HStack {
                                                Text("\(event.eventDate ?? NSDate(), formatter: ViewEventsView.eventDateFormatter)")
                                                    .fixedSize()
                                                    .foregroundColor(.green)
                                                MenuOverlayView(recipient: recipient, event: event)
                                            }
                                        }
                                        .padding(iPhone ? 1 : 5)
                                        .font(iPhone ? .caption : .title3)
                                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            .padding()
                            .frame(minWidth: iPhone ? 160 : 320, maxWidth: .infinity,
                                   minHeight: iPhone ? 160 : 320, maxHeight: .infinity)
                            .background(Color(UIColor.systemGroupedBackground))
                            .mask(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
                            .shadow(radius: 5)
                            .padding(iPhone ? 5: 10)
                        }
                        .padding()
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                                        HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        // MARK: self is Current View
                        // You can give whatever View to Conver
                        //                        print(convertToScrollView(content: {
                        //                            self
                        //                        }).contentSize)
                        exportPDF {
                            self
                        } completion: { status, url in
                            if let url = url, status {
                                PDFUrl = url
                                showShareSheet.toggle()
                            } else {
                                print("Failed to Produce PDF")
                            }
                        }
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up.fill")
                            .font(.title2)
                            .foregroundColor(.green)
                    })
                })
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showShareSheet) {
                PDFUrl = nil
            } content: {
                if let PDFUrl = PDFUrl {
                    ShareSheet(urls: [PDFUrl])
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: click the Pause after the freeze and inspect every thread. Did any threads enter  `exportPDF`? Also make sure the completion (being a UI operation) runs on main thread.

Comment: Will check that out.. and report back.. Thanks @timbretimbre

Comment: I do see on the main Thread (Thread 1) that#14 0x00000001044e8080 in closure #2 in View.exportPDF<τ_0_0>(content:completion:) is in the thread ... Which is in the do { try } secant of exportPDF view extension.  I Then let it continue to run, and watching the debugger it almost seems like it is going thru the entire CoreData content. not just what's in the view.

Comment: After letting it continue to run and just waiting for all activity in the debugger window to stop.. pretty much the same results in the main thread.. just a View.exportPDF closure 2 content:completion: message.

Comment: Still can't solve this one...